# Is it true that every (smooth) homomorphism of lie groups can be written a submersion followed by an immersion?

Tags: manifolds

Is it true that every (smooth) homomorphism of lie groups can be written a submersion followed by an immersion?

This isn't clear to me!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hint:  given $\varphi:G \to H$, consider $G \twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{Im}\varphi \hookrightarrow H$>

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:G\to H$ be a smooth map of Lie groups. Its kernel $K$ is a closed normal subgroup of $G$, so $G/K$ is a Lie group and $f$ factors as the composition of the quotient map $G\to G/K$, which is a submersion, and an injection $G/K\to H$, which is an immersion.

Comment: One has to do this slightly contorted thing because $G/K$ need not be a closed subgroup of $H$; its topology can be very different to the topology of its image in $H$.

Comment: Hi Mariano. Why is it clear that the quotient map is a lie group morphism? And moreover, why are these maps submersions and immersions? Could you elaborate please, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should check a book like Lee's book on smooth manifolds.